# in Classic ASP: Convert comma separated string

Tags: string, asp-classic

How do I convert, in Classic ASP,  this (example) comma separated Querystring

```
Illinois, Iowa, Wisconsin, Indiana, Kentucky,Missouri to

'Illinois', 'Iowa', 'Wisconsin', 'Indiana', 'Kentuck','Missouri'
```

I am using Dreamweaver and need this format to select records from a table which contain one of the states in the string Using IN clause.

Comment: Don't do that! **NEVER** stick unvalidated get parameters into a sql query directly. Use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just the conversion here it is:

```
origstring = "Illinois, Iowa, Wisconsin, Indiana, Kentucky, Missouri"
convertedstring = "'" &replace(origstring, ", ","', '") &"'"
```

But let's say you (or anyone else) have a querystring with states:

```
strinclause = ""
arrstates = Split(Request.QueryString("states"), ",")
if(Ubound(arrstates) > 0) Then 
    for i=0 to Ubound(arrstates)
      'VALIDATE/CLEAN YOUR ARRAY ITEMS AND BUILD YOUR STRING IN THIS WAY:
       strinclause = strinclause & "'" &arrstates(i)& "',"
    next
    'NOW REMOVE LAST COMA
    strinclause = Left(strinclause,Len(strinclause)-1)
end if
'HERE YOU CAN USE YOUR STRING THAT WILL BE IN THE FORMAT YOU ASKED
```

Answer (score 0):

Jut spitballing, but you could do something like this:

```
<%
    Dim qs : qs = Trim("" & Request.QueryString("states") ' e.g.  "Illinois, Iowa, Wisconsin, Indiana, Kentucky, Missouri"

    Dim cmd : Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = db.connection ' defined elsewhere
    cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient ' 3
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText ' 1
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 90

    dim inp : inp = Split(qs, ",") ' states
    dim sql, i : ReDim sql (ubound(inp)) ' for sql

    for i = 0 to ubound(inp)
            sql(i) = "select ?" ' parameter in string
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p" & i, adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, inp(i)) ' actual typed parameter object
    next
    cmd.CommandText = "select id, stock from warehouse where state in (" & Join(sql, " union ") & ")"

    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Do While Not rs.eof
            response.write "<p>" & rs("id") & ": " & rs("stock") & "</p>"
            rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
%>
```